# Sending mail from eml file with attachments

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, eml

I am using javax mail api for sending emails.

How can i send an email when the email body is given from an eml file?

I also need to add attachments to this email which are on my local disk.

Example of how to send email from an eml file will help a lot.

I only need the part of adding the eml without the server settings and etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("file.eml");
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session,is);
```